# Unable to start Oracle UCM IdcAnalyze

Tags: oracle, analyzer

I tried to follow this guidance https://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/keep_your_ucm_instance_in_shape to run the analyzer from shell,(\cs\bin) ./IdcAnalyze -g

It was showing this error instead of popping up a gui for analyzer

[image: <screen shot>]

I have been trying to google for 4 hours but I got nothing and in addition, actually I am trying to clean up UCM files (about 30gbs contains pdf and tiff) and this IdcAnalyzer seems to be the only solution.

Is there any other mechanism to perform the safe clean up?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your database settings are not set. If you fire up the ucm/cs/bin/SystemProperties program (which is not an applet you can run from within the UCM/WCC Console), then you should be able to check you database settings.

It would be *much* more useful if you copy-pasted the text (the whole text) rather than one screenshot that doesn't show a great deal; although the cause does appear to be that it can't find its database configuration.

I have seen it drop its database config after (upgrade/patching, I think).

You didn't say what version of UCM/WCC you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the the reason for this error is that DB configuration details are not put in the System Properties applet . Reason for that is all the applets when started as stand-alone (from /bin) will look for the JdbcConnection string which is picked from the System Properties applet .